# Laravel 5.4, user cannot see dashboard if they don't own anything

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

The problem is, is that when I sign a new user up (in my application a 'charity owner'), they are redirected to their dashboard.

On the dashboard, displays the all the charities that the user owns and any donations made to them in another table.

However, because the user has not added their charity to the database yet I am getting undefined variables.

```
 @forelse($ownedCharities as $owned)

     <td> {{ $owned->name }} </td>
     <td>  Not Available </td>
     <td> <p id="desc"> {{ $owned->description }} </p> <a href="#"> <p style="color: #000;" class="seeMore"> See more... </p> </a> </td>
     <a href="#"> <button class="btn btn-danger btnPopover"
                                    data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top"> Delete </button> </a> </td>

     <td> <a href="{{ route('ownedCharities.edit', $owned->id) }}"> <button class="btn btn-warning"> Edit </button> </a> </td>

 </tr>

 @empty

     <p> No charities owned </p>

 @endforelse
```

I am using Blade's @forelse

Comment: what 'undefined variables' are you getting? please include the error.

Comment: @lagbox ErrorException in aba65c26bee51d013e4c3925db1659b80ae8cf35.php line 172:
Undefined variable: owned (View: C:\wamp64\www\EasyDonationNew\laravel\resources\views\charityowner.blade.php)

Comment: @lagbox If I was to add a charity, this error would go because the user would now own a charity. Is there a way to just show the page so I can add a message to display to the user, but they can carry on using the application as normal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use php functions in blade like to see if they are or not defined or has some value

```
@isset($records)
    // $records is defined and is not null
@endisset

@empty($records)
    // $records is "empty"...
@endempty
```

Comment: Would I add this under my foreach loop or replace?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Null coalescing operator` which is introduces in PHP 7

```
$records ?? ""
```